# Are there a sub-class of transactions which do not change EVM State?

Tags: go-ethereum, consensus, state-transition

I was reading this article on https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/ . It said all transactions which change the EVM state must be broadcasted to the whole network .
Just wondering if there's a subclass of transactions which do not change the state .
Thank you

Comment: if you just read something from the chain you also send a transaction but it doesnt need to be broadcasted. every kind of interaction with the chain is basically a transaction

Answer (score 0):

No, all transaction mined in the blockchain can potentially cause a state change.

It is possible to execute a contract off-chain, but I won't call those execution a transaction.